# MySQL: ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'col1', computed virtual column insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
create table TableName5 (     col1 varchar(200),     col2 varchar(200),     col3 varchar(200) generated
always as ('col1' + 'col2') stored );
```

The `col3` is supposed to be a computed column - the value in `col1` plus the value in `col2`.

The create query works OK.

However trying to insert values:

```
insert into TableName5 (col1, col2) values ('a', 'b');
```

Results in

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'col1'
```

error.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

I tried using a different create query:

```
create table TableName5 (     col1 varchar(200),     col2 varchar(200),     col3 varchar(200) generated
always as concat(col1, ' ', col2) stored );
```

but got a syntax error on it

Comment: col1 + col2 makes both a integer, as text can't be summed. and what do you want to be in col3 ' ab' ?

Comment: @nbk I want `col3` to be `ab`, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your original you had stings cl1 and clo2 so the result was col1col2

as i satd you can't sum varchar or text you need CONCAT

```
create table TableName5 (     col1 varchar(200),     col2 varchar(200),     col3 varchar(200) generated
always as (CONCAT(`col1` , `col2`)) stored );
```

```
insert into TableName5 (col1, col2) values ('a', 'b');
```

```
SELECT * FROM TableName5
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | ab |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k7NJPsUt)

Answer (score 1):

```
create table TableName5 (
    col1 varchar(200),
    col2 varchar(200),
    col3 varchar(200) generated always as (concat(col1, ' ', col2)) stored
);
```